# How can I handle a file in python 2.7 to separate them line-by-line to insert into database?

Tags: python-2.7, file-handling

I am  very novice in python 2.7 who is unable to handle a large file( Data-sets for thesis). suppose my data-set(mmd.txt) has 3 attributes.

```
1,2,3
0.2,2.3,4
5.4,2,3
1.3,2.4,3
9.2,2.6,7.22
5.4,2,3
5.66,4.25,7.6
45.2,52.6,7.22
5.4,20.2,3.6
5.66,4.25,7.6
```

here is a the data-set (mmd.txt). you can see that every line has three attributes separated by comma and each line defines a row.So how can I handle them/separate them to insert into database?please put your suggestion so that I can understand. Thanks for reading my post.

Comment: what is your *database*?

Comment: my database name is thesis :)

Comment: How are you planning on inserting into your database?

Comment: if you see first line 1,2,3. I want 1 in one  column,2 in second column,3 in third column.

Comment: `import csv; r = csv.reader(open("mmd.txt"))`, then iterate over `r`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to the wonderful world of Python.

What are you trying to do is easily accomplishable. First you need to open the file using the `open()` function. Than you can `split('\n')` it into an array containing your lines. Lastly you can `for` loop through and `split(',')` the lines, separating the comma-separated values into an array. This is just the basic framework you'd have to follow and needs to be managed accordingly to the size of your input. In practice, it would look like this:

```
FILE_NAME = "mmd.txt"
with open(FILE_NAME, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().split('\n');
    for line in lines:
        print line.split(',')
```

This code will print your parameters nicely separated inside an array. I think you can go on with that.

If you want to learn more about the language, I'd recommend Codecademy's [Python Track](https://www.codecademy.com/tracks/python).

Happy coding